# Rudin's Definition of Angle-Preservation

Tags: complex-analysis

I have several questions and an observation. There are several related questions on mathstack but I do not think my post is a duplicate. Basically, I want to understand the geometry that motivates the formula.

We have that $f$ maps a region containing $z_0$ into the plane, and then if

$\underset{r\to 0}\lim e^{-i\theta}\frac{f(z_0+re^{i\theta})-f(z_0)}{|f(z_0+re^{i\theta})-f(z_0)|}$ exists and is independent of $\theta$, then $f$ is said to preserve angles.

So far so good. You pick a $\theta,$ move along the ray from $z_0$ to $w=z_0+re^{i\theta}$, evaluate $f$ as in the formula, take the difference, and calculate the direction from the origin. Then rotate the result through an angle of $-\theta$.

First question: what is the significance of the final rotation? Obviously, it's necessary: for if we take $f=1$, then without it, the limit is $e^{i\theta}$.

Rudin then claims "the requirement is that for any two rays $L$ and $L'$, starting at $z_0$, the angle which their images $f(L)$ and $f(L')$ make at $f(z_0)$ is 
the same as that made by $L$ and $L$, in size as well as in orientation."

I have tried without success to prove this analytically from his definition. I am not even sure what he means by "the angle which their images $f(L)$ and $f(L')$ make at $f(z_0)$" since the image under $f$ of the ray will ordinarily be a curve, not a line. I'd like to find a careful proof (hints are ok) of Rudin's claim.

Now, an observation: Rudin's formula seems abstruse to me (probably because of my lack of mathematical sophistication). Wouldn't it be clearer to first define angle-preservation in terms of $\mathbb R$-linear transformations, since in the end, we're going to look at tangents of compositions of $f$ with curves into $\mathbb C$ from real intervals i.e. differentials? That is, say that if $T$ is some $\mathbb R$-linear transformation, then it preserves angles if and only if $\frac{\langle z,w\rangle}{|z||w|}=\frac{\langle Tz,Tw\rangle}{|Tz||Tw|}$. Then, I think it's easy to show that either $T(z)=az$ or $T(z)=a\overline z$ for some $a\neq 0.$ With this fact, we than  get all the results Rudin gets in what follows by applying this definition to the differential $Df$, because it is an $\mathbb R$-linear map.

Finally, if my observation works, how might I prove that it is equivalent to Rudin's definition? I don't want a full proof here, just hints.

Comment: Since the denominator is real (so has argument zero), you need to compensate for the argument of the numerator hence the $e^{-i\theta}$ - in the definition of the complex derivative that happens automatically - for conformal $f$ at a point $z_0$, the curves $f(L), f(L')$ are nonsingular at $f(z_0)$ so have tangents there and that is the angle you want -